# Switch with 48 port all PoE

Tags: switch

We are looking for a 48 port PoE switch. 
My budget is around $1200. Is there any switch that is reliable for that price range?

Comment: Just FYI - Shopping questions are generally discouraged, since they are very narrow in their relevance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used the Netgear GS748TP at several sites for VoIP implementations and have had good results with them:

http://www.netgear.com/business/products/switches/smart-switches/GS748TP.aspx

You have to deal with the web interface to configure it. It is a little clunky. If you can get past it, they are a really decent switch for the price.

The bad thing is they are about $1,350 right now. Though if you search hard enough, you can find one for about $1,230.

Comment: It seems very odd to me that Netgear (and all brands for that matter) only seem to offer 48-port densities at gigabit speeds. I don't know of any network that requires 48 PoE ports AND gigabit. Most phones are 100Mb and I don't know many places that need 48 WiFi points. I think most people would prefer to pay a few hundred bucks less and live with 100Mb. But I guess that's why they don't do it, because they want to force you onto higher specced equipment.

Comment: Considering that gigabit ethernet is mainsteram nowadays, it probably costs them the same, or less, to make the hardware gigabit over 10/100.

Answer (score 2):

I have a bunch of [HP E2610-48](http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/us/en/sm/WF25a/12883-12883-4172267-4172301-4172277-3751584.html) switches I'm happy with.  They're providing POE on all ports and have a lifetime warranty.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at D-Link switches. We're using the DES-3028P (24 10/100 PoE + 4 GigE) for our VoIP deployments. Cost is about $500/switch for us. These are also "fully managed" (telnet/SSH/SNMP/etc) switches.

I believe they also have a 48 port version of the switch, but I can't recall the model number off the top of my head.

BTW, it may not matter, but take a look at the PoE output for any switch you get. Some can't power all ports at 15W (or even a fraction of that). That was one reason we chose the DES-3028P (it does full 15W/port).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to step into a NetGear managed unit (with Lifetime warranty) for under $1K
model FS752TPSNA  is what I have used in the past - works like a charm.

Comment: It looks like that switch only presents 24 PoE ports. Also looks like EOL on that line of switches according to the Netgear site.